# Query for summing all rows prior to date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm not quite sure how to explain it but the demo spreadsheet illustrates the result I am trying to achieve.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TYkvKgVShXwvvUbiuNrQdyJFng4eOd3-0cPSkqeANzQ/edit?usp=sharing

Edit: permissions have been fixed.

Comment: we can't access the spreadsheet you shared. Please fix permissions.

Comment: Hello, the spreadsheet you have posted does not allow access. Please set the sharing preferences to "anyone with the link".

Comment: Oops, permissions have been fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a couple of formulas in the spreadsheet you shared.

To get the unique dates, I used in I1

```
 ={"Date"; unique(A2:A)}
```

To compute the sum for 'Apple', I entered in J1

```
={"Apple"; ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(unique(A2:A), QUERY({A2:A, SUMIF(IF(B2:B = "Apple", row(A2:A),),  "<="&row(A2:A), C2:C)}, "where Col2 > 0", 0), 2, 0)))}
```

For 'Tesla' the same formula was used, replacing 'Apple' with 'Tesla'.

See if that helps?

[image]

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply, but yes this was exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks so much!!!